# Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is it always possible to find the limit of a function without using [L'Hôpital Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) or [Series Expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html)?

For example,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{-1}x-x}{x^3}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan^{-1}x-x}{x^3}$$

Comment: Should this be tagged pre-calculus instead of calculus?

Comment: The OP knows all the answers but perhaps wants to seek solutions outside analysis.

Comment: For $(\tan x - x)/x^3$ and $(\sin x-x)/x^3$ using only $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to1$ and not assuming in advance that the limits exist, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/158134/1242.

Answer (score 84):

> $$L_1=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}\quad L_2=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\quad L_3=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}\\L_4=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}\quad L_5=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{-1}x-x}{x^3}\quad L_6=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan^{-1}x-x}{x^3}$$

---

Yes if we know beforehand the limit exists.

---

For $L_1$:
$$L_1=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}\\
L_1=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan 2x-2x}{8x^3}\\
4L_1=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\tan2x-x}{x^3}\\
3L_1=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\tan{2x}-\tan x}{x^3}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}x\frac{\frac1{1-\tan^2x}-1}{x^2}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\tan x)^3}{x^3}=1\\
\large L_1=\frac13$$

---

For $L_2$:
$$L_2=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\\
L_2=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x-2x}{8x^3}\\
4L_2=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\sin 2x-x}{x^3}\\
3L_2=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\sin 2x-\sin x}{x^3}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}\frac{\sin x}x\\
L_2=\frac13\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}\\
L_2=\frac13\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos 2x-1}{4x^2}\\
4L_2=\frac13\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos 2x-1}{x^2}\\
3L_2=\frac13\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos 2x-\cos x}{x^2}\\
3L_2=\frac13\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)(2\cos x+1)}{x^2}\\
3L_2=\frac13\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)(2\cos x+1)}{x^2}\\
\large L_2=-\frac16$$

---

For $L_3$:
$$L_3=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}\\
L_3=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+2x)-2x}{4x^2}\\
2L_3=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\ln(1+2x)-x}{x^2}\\
L_3=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\ln(1+2x)-\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\\
2L_3=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+2x)-2\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\\
2L_3=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2}\right)}{x^2}\\
\large L_3=-\frac12
$$

---

For $L_4$:
$$L_4=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}\\
4L_4=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-2x-1}{x^2}\\
3L_4=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-e^x-x}{x^2}\\
12L_4=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{4x}-e^{2x}-2x}{x^2}\\
6L_4=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12e^{4x}-\frac12e^{2x}-x}{x^2}\\
3L_4=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12e^{4x}-\frac32e^{2x}+e^x}{x^2}\\
3L_4=\frac12\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x(e^x-1)^2(e^x+2)}{x^2}\\
\large L_4=\frac12$$

---

For $L_5$:
$$L_5=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{-1}x-x}{x^3}\\
8L_5=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{-1}2x-2x}{x^3}\\
4L_5=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\sin^{-1}2x-x}{x^3}\\
3L_5=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\sin^{-1}2x-\sin^{-1}x}{x^3}\\
6L_5=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{-1}2x-2\sin^{-1}x}{x^3}\\
6L_5=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(-4 x^3-2 \sqrt{1-4 x^2} \sqrt{1-x^2} x+2 x\right)}{x^3}\\
6L_5=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-4 x^3+2x(1- \sqrt{1-4 x^2} \sqrt{1-x^2})}{x^3}\\
6L_5=\lim_{x\to0}-4+2\frac{(1- \sqrt{1-5 x^2+4x^4})}{x^2}\\
6L_5=\lim_{x\to0}-4+2\frac{(1- \sqrt{1-5 x^2+4x^4})}{x^2}$$
Since you would consider binomial theorem as series expansion, if not well and good, if yes, then I'll do:
Now let $\sqrt{1-5 x^2+4x^4}=\sum a_kx^k$, squaring both sides, $$1-5x^2+4x^4=a_0^2+2a_0a_1x+(2a_0a_2+a_1^2)x^2+(2a_0a_3+a_1a_2)x^3+(2a_0a_4+2a_1a_3+a_2^2)x^4+...$$
Now taking positive branch:
$$a_0=1,a_1=0,a_2=-5/2,a_3=0,a_4=-9/8,...$$
So:
$$6L_5=\lim_{x\to0}-4+2\frac{(1- (1-5x^2/2-9x^4/8...))}{x^2}\\\large L_5=\frac16$$

---

For $L_6$:
$$L_6=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan^{-1}x-x}{x^3}\\
4L_6=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\tan^{-1}2x-x}{x^3}\\
3L_6=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan^{-1}2x-2\tan^{-1}x}{2x^3}\\
6L_6=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{2 x^3}{3 x^2+1}\right)}{x^3}\\
L_6=-\frac13$$

Comment: Don't you use, in your computations, the assumption that the limits exist and are finite?

Comment: @PeterFranek yes, this method works only if you assure the limit exists

Comment: @ADG. For $L_5$ you do not need to use any binomial formula or series, you can just multiply both numerator and denominator by $1+\sqrt{1-5x^2+4x^4}$.

Comment: This is at best a partial answer. You have answered the OP's particular problems, sure, but you haven't answered the more broad question I think OP was trying to get at: can limits of all "nice" functions be in principle solved without series expansion or L'hopital?

Comment: Haha, you are quite sneaky...

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Sounds way too broad.

Answer (score 65):

Using only trigonometric identities, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/508988), it is shown that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x-\tan(x)}=-\frac12\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, if we subtract from $1$, we get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{\tan(x)-x}=\frac32\tag{2}
$$
Using the limits proven geometrically in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151), we can derive
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)(1-\cos(x))}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)}x\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\frac1{1+\cos(x)}\\
&=\frac12\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
we can divide $(3)$ by $(2)$ to get
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}=\frac13}\tag{4}
$$
and we can multiply $(1)$ by $(4)$ to get
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}=-\frac16}\tag{5}
$$
Note that $(4)$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)-x}{\tan^3(x)}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3}{\tan^3(x)}\\
&=\frac13\cdot1\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, substituting $x\mapsto\tan^{-1}(x)$,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)-x}{x^3}=-\frac13}\tag{7}
$$
Similarly, $(5)$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{\sin^3(x)}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3}{\sin^3(x)}\\
&=-\frac16\cdot1\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, substituting $x\mapsto\sin^{-1}(x)$,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^{-1}(x)-x}{x^3}=\frac16}\tag{9}
$$

---

Using the Binomial Theorem, we have
$$
\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n-1-x
=\frac{n-1}{2n}x^2+\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^k}{n^k}\tag{10}
$$
and for $|x|\le1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^k}{n^k}\right|
&=|x|^3\left|\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^{k-3}}{n^k}\right|\\
&\le |x|^3\sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac1{k!}\\[6pt]
&=|x|^3\left(e-\tfrac52\right)\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(10)$ and $(11)$ and taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ yields
$$
\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac12+O(|x|)\tag{12}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac12}\tag{13}
$$
A simple corollary of $(13)$ is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=1\tag{14}
$$
Therefore, it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{(e^x-1)^2}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{(e^x-1)^2}\\
&=\frac12\tag{15}
\end{align}
$$
If we substitute $x\mapsto\log(1+x)$ in $(15)$, we get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\log(1+x)}{x^2}=\frac12\tag{16}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)-x}{x^2}=-\frac12}\tag{17}
$$

Comment: Why the downvote? I thought an approach that did not assume the limits exist and didn't use derivatives would be good (such as for presentation to a pre-calculus class).

Comment: i wish users of MSE learn good habits like "do not downvote without giving a comment". This is especially more relevant to a well written answer like this. Anyway I like the solutions to limit problems which avoid the use of derivative. +1 from my end. Also the derivation of $(17)$ from $(13)$ was a new one for me.

Answer (score 19):

In general, $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)\cdot x^k}{k!}}{x^n} = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} $. This can be proven using the Mean Value Theorem $n$ times and induction.

Comment: This is, of course, a form of l'Hôpital's theorem.

Comment: The Mean Value Theorem does not requires l'Hôpital's rule to prove, nor vice-versa for most cases where the limit is at a real value (as opposed to infinity).

Comment: What I mean is that this case of l'Hôpital's theorem is easily proved using the mean value theorem. So, applying this case can really be "without l'Hôpital or Taylor expansion"? Your assertion is mostly the same as Taylor expansion, I believe. Anyway, the question is not well posed. To me, applying $\lim_{x\to0}(\sin x)/x=1$ is just the same as using the derivative of $\sin$, so l'Hôpital or Taylor.

Comment: No, that is circular logic. You need that limit before you can even compute $ \frac{d}{dx} \sin x $, which is needed for all three things you listed. It is most certainly not that same thing; in fact, it's not even a subject of calculus so much as precalculus and basic limits.

Comment: The method above uses repeated derivatives and essentially uses the proof technique of Taylor's series. I believe the OP wanted to have a technique which avoids differentiation altogether. But when we disable differentiation, it is almost impossible to evaluate the above limits. In some of the cases if we assume the existence of the limit then we can evaluate the limit by simple algebraic/trigonometric manipulation. But for existence we need differentiation.

Comment: The equivalence I cited does not relay on Taylor Series and can be proved with only the Mean Value Theorem for derivatives. But yes, it does rely on differentation. The OP only said he doesn't want Taylor Series or l'Hospital's rule applied.

Comment: I have to disagree. Actually you don't need to know that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ before computing $\frac{d}{dx}\sin x$.

Comment: @MrPink : Feel free to demonstrate how to evaluate $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x+h) - \sin(x)}{h}$ without the use of that limit (and without the use of an equivalent limit).

Comment: @EricTowers Here is a proof that $\frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x$ which doesn't use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4o7sraVMZg

Comment: @MrPink : False.  That limit is used to pretend that the handwavy "not actually a triangle" is similar to the main right triangle (around 1:39).  These are not similar triangles since one of these is not a triangle.  Replacing the curved edge of the not-a-triangle with the tangent line to the circle can be justified in the limit, but is not justified in the video.

Comment: @EricTowers Even though they use the similarity property in the video, it's actually not needed, because you can notice that the top left angle on the triangle is $\theta$.

Comment: @MrPink : The similarity of the triangle with the triangle that the not-triangle approximates in the limit is crucial to the argument.  *Both* $\theta$s must be interior angles of actual triangles.  The not-a-triangle is not a triangle, it requires use of a limit equivalent to the one specified in my comment to replace it with an actual triangle.  And only then does the similarity argument work.

Comment: @MrPink : The region in the upper left has a circular arc as one side.  This is not a triangle.  Replacing it with a triangle is only valid in the limit that $\Delta \theta \rightarrow 0$.  Of course, then you are right back to the limit I specified in my challenge comment.  That limit is hiding in the zoom from 0:48 to 0:51.

Comment: @EricTowers Can you explain where exactly $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ "pops out"? Yes, I understand that it is not a triangle, but you can see that it "approaches" a triangle. Still, I don't see where that particular sine limit "is used" in the argument at all.

Comment: @MrPink : You say it "approaches" a triangle.  It does so in the limit $\Delta \theta \rightarrow 0$.  That is, this approximate geometric construction is computing the average rate of change of sine between $\theta$ and $\theta + \Delta \theta$ in the limit as $\Delta \theta \rightarrow 0$.  Call "$\theta$" by the name "$x$" and call "$\Delta \theta$" by the name "$h$" and you have exactly the limit I wrote.

Comment: @EricTowers I understand that it approaches a triangle in the limit $\Delta \theta\to 0$, but why do you have to take the sine of that angle?

Comment: @MrPink : The choice of which leg of the resulting limit triangle is used in the ratio, chooses the sine.  If we chose the other leg, we would be discussing cosine.

Comment: @EricTowers Doesn't the fact that $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is differentiable there prove that the circular curve can be replaced by the line segment as $\Delta \theta\to 0$?

Comment: @MrPink : "Replaced".  So now you're making my argument -- Actually evaluating the rate of change in sine for a finite angle is too hard, so we take the limit, pretending that the function is adequately approximated by the tangent.

Comment: @EricTowers Proving the differentiability of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ justifies that the arc can be replaced by a line segment. Where did that use $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$?

Comment: @MrPink : "by **a** line segment".  It is not enough to replace by **a** line segment.  It is required that the line segment produce a right triangle having the correct relation between a specific acute angle and its opposite.

Comment: @MrPink : Also, it appears that you are unwilling or unable to recognize that your original claim is wrong and the video directly uses the limit under question.  Consequently, you are wasting our time.  I won't have any more of my time wasted by you.  Perhaps you will find someone willing to re-explain and re-explain this to you until you finally arrive at the correct conclusion.  I won't be spending that time.

Comment: @MrPink : The last I will write about this (from August 25 at 17:45) : "... demonstrate how to evaluate $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x+h)−\sin(x)}{h}$ without the use of that limit (and without the use of an equivalent limit).".  \begin{align*} \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x+h)−\sin(x)}{h} &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(h)+\cos(x)\sin(h)−\sin(x)}{h} \\ &= \sin(x) \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(h) -1}{h} + \cos(x) \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h} \text{,}\end{align*} so the use of either limit to justify linearization is the use of an equivalent limit.

Comment: @EricTowers Any line segment there would produce a right triangle, because any tangent line to the circle would be perpendicular to the ray emanating from the origin and going through the point of tangency.

Comment: @EricTowers And the more $\Delta\theta$ gets close to $0$, the more the 'not-a-triangle' gets close to a triangle.

Comment: @EricTowers I think I finally understand it: It can be proved that $\frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x$ using the fact that tangent line is perpendicular to radius and that $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ "flattens out" when zooming closer and closer (because it is differentiable). *Then*, the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x$ implies that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, because, as you say, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin (x+h)-\sin x}{h}=\sin x\,\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos h-1}{h}+\cos x\, \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h}$. Still, this doesn't mean that you have to compute the sin x/x limit before the derivative of sin

Comment: @MrPink : The tangent line is irrelevant.  The point on the circle is never on the tangent line.  Continuing to think you have proven something using the tangent line is continuing to be wrong.  The limit I wrote contains the unavoidable ingredients to get the **correct** point actually on the circle.  Until your process uses points **on** the circle, your process is wrong.

Comment: @EricTowers It's never on the tangent line, but it can get arbitrarily near. That's what the derivatives are about. Why shouldn't this reasoning work?

Comment: @MrPink : Point not on circle = wrong.

Comment: @EricTowers But **why** is that wrong when the error can be made arbitrarily small?

Comment: @MrPink : You can't find the error until you can compute it correctly.  You can't compute it correctly if the point is not on the circle.  You are of course free to solve the wrong problem, using points not on the circle.  While doing so may coincidentally give the correct answer, trusting a garbage result is wrong.

Comment: @Mr Pink: Eric Towers is actually correct here. You've severely misunderstood the point of the video. The video isn't a rigorous proof, but rather, a visualization to help build a geometric intuition for why the limit formula for the derivative works for the sine function. In order for the asymptotic triangular similarity between the two regions in the video to be established, one needs to first perform a linearization on the point of tangency of the circle, and then actually prove that the angle between the tangent line and the horizontal axis is the angle that was claimed to be.

Comment: @Mr Pink: Also, while lim sin(θ)/θ (θ —> 0) was never explicitly referred to in the video, it is definitely implicit in the calculation that was shown in the video when appealing to the similar triangles. Notice that by definition, Δy = sin(θ + Δθ) – sin(θ), so they ultimately just used the limit definition of the derivative in abbreviated form. Additionally, the reason the visualization works is because they are able to assert that the triangles are similar in the limit, but this assertion is actually equivalent to lim sin(θ)/θ (θ —> 0) = 1 to begin with.

Comment: @Mr Pink: In other words, they appealed to the same argument that is normally used to prove lim sin(Δθ)/Δθ (Δθ —> 0), except they just an arbitrary angle θ for the tangency point instead of the special case θ = 0. In essence, the video just visually demonstrates the above limit, and then presents an arbitrarily phase shifted and vertically shifted version of it. They still had use the argument to visually demonstrate said limit to demonstrate the more general version for the derivative.

Comment: @Angel "one needs to first perform a linearization on the point of tangency of the circle" Yes. And that is not a problem at all as one can prove that $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is differentiable, hence it represents a line locally as $\Delta \theta\to 0$. That way, you can prove that $\frac{d}{d\theta}\sin\theta =\cos\theta$ using the argument with triangles and then, using the limit definition of the derivative, you can prove $\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$.

Comment: @EricTowers You can approximate the circle by regular $n$-gon line segments if you will, and crank up $n$ to infinity. Just observe the construction as $n$ gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: @MrPink : This also does not correct the errors you have made:  Essentially every choice of $n$ segments fails to produce a line perpendicular to the radius, so is *not* a tangent line.  Additionally, the only points in your polygon *on* the circle are the endpoints of the segments, so the "error" you are calculating is for a point not on the circle.  It has twice been patiently explained to you that your original argument is wrong.  Moving the goalposts to another wrong argument is a waste of everyone's time again; I won't be participating further.

Comment: @EricTowers The $n$-gon thing doesn't work here, OK. But still, one can use the differentiability of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. The argument is not wrong, you can see nicomezi's comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307345/geometric-proof-for-the-derivative-of-sine

Comment: @MrPink You certainly did ignore the rest of my comment and decided to cherry-pick a quote of out its context, huh.