# Solve $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm trying to solve this limit

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$$

Solving using L'hopital rule, we have:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x-1}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\sin x}{6x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\cos x}{6}=-\frac{1}{6}.$$

Am I right?

I'm trying to solve this using change of variables, I need help.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I didn't understand the answer and the commentaries, I'm looking for an answer using *change of variables*.

Comment: This is the correct value.

Comment: You can checked it with Taylor series.

Comment: Is it right using L'hôpital rule several times? In page 109 of Rudin's mathematical analysis book he says in order to use this rule we have to have $f'(x)/g'(x)\to A$.

Comment: @Fabien really interesting, but can we take the limit in an infinite sum?

Comment: @user42912, more than taking the limit, you can evaluate in $0$.

Comment: @Fabien yes, I know this is true if this sum is finite, but why this is true in this infinite sum.

Comment: @user42912, take the exponential on $0$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157903/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frac-tanx-xx3/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose the below counts as a change of variable.

Assuming that the limit exists, then you can compute the limit as follows:

Replace $x$ by $3x$, then the limit (say $L$) is

$$L  = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 3x - 3x}{27x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3\sin x - 3x - 4\sin^3 x}{27x^3} = $$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{\sin x - x}{x^3}\right) - \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4}{27}\left(\frac{\sin^3 x}{x^3}\right)$$

(we used the formula $\sin 3x = 3\sin x - 4 \sin^3 x$).

Thus we get

$$L = \frac{L}{9} - \frac{4}{27} \implies L = -\frac{1}{6}$$

Of course, we still need to prove that the limit exists.

Comment: It's EXACTLY I was looking for, thank you very much

Comment: Excellent answer.