# Calculate the limit : $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}$ WITHOUT using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was given a task to find  $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}$$ at my school today. I thought it was an easy problem and started differentiating denominator and numerator to calculate the limit but the teacher then said we aren't allowed to use  L'Hopital's rule, but to "play around" with known limits and limit definition. I got stuck here since I can't really think of a way to do this, and according to my teacher, there are at least 4 ways. A subtle hint would be enough. Thanks.

Comment: Is the Taylor expansion of $\sin$ known?

Comment: @DanielFischer Since Taylor works anywhere where L'Hospital works, I presume not...

Comment: @DanielFischer Now that's a really cool idea and a fairly simple one to do too. We haven't done series expansions yet in school, so i don't think it's allowed, but that's awesome.

Comment: @Transcendental Just a warning: L'Hospital is basically equivalent to taking the Taylor expansion up to only the first two terms, so if your teacher wants you to calculate without L'Hospital, that probably also includes no Taylor.

Comment: @5xum Well yes, i suppose that's right. Also, as I've mentioned, we haven't really covered series expansion so he probably didn't meant that ( that might be one of his 3 ways).

Comment: That is not a duplicate...  $\tan x$ is different enough from $\sin x$ that the questions should be separate.  Yes, they should be linked, but not duplicate.

Comment: @anorton: This one then: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856030/solve-lim-x-to-0-frac-sin-x-xx3

Comment: @Aryabhata Much better; thanks for the link.

Comment: See here for an answer which doesn't assume the existence of the limit: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157903/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frac-tanx-xx3/158134#158134

Comment: See also: [Determine $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}}=\frac{1}{6}$, without L'Hospital or Taylor](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217081)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x-\sin2x}{8x^3}\\
4L-L = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\frac12\sin2x-x+\sin x}{x^3}$$
which simplifies to the product of three expressions of the form $\frac{\sin y}{y}$

Comment: +10 for actually not using the L'Hospital rule (even in its "oh I'm not L'hospital, I'm Taylor" disguise).

Comment: I find this proof looks very neat, however I don't understand the last step you did. Do you mind explaining it? 
I don't find it obvious, what 4L is.
Ah ok, problem solved. Haha, nice.

Comment: The only thing this proof assume is the existence of $L$.

Comment: So for instance $ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\cos (x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\cos (2x)= \lim_{x\rightarrow}2\cos^2 x -1$. So $$ L=2L^2 -1$$

Comment: a related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508733/lim-x-to0-fracx-sin-xx-tan-x-without-using-lhopital

Comment: This needs a proof that $L$ exists. -1 till then :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This method is 'Taylor series inspired,' but I think I can say in good faith that it fits your requirements of not using l'Hospital's Rule or Taylor's Theorem.

We observe first that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3} = \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{(-x) - \sin(-x)}{(-x)^3} = \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{x - \sin x}{x^3}$$

Thus, $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$$
so we can focus on behavior of $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$ for $x>0$ to evaluate the limit.

Set $f(x) = x - \sin x$.  We're going to try to bound $f$ with polynomials so we can use the Squeeze Theorem.  Since integration preserves inequalities, in the sense that if $f(t) \le g(t)$ for $0 \le t \le x$ then $\int_0^x f(t) \,dt \le \int_0^x g(t) \,dt$, we will find these polynomials by differentiating $f$ some number of times, finding polynomials that bound the derivative, then integrating. Since we want to find the limit of $\frac{f}{x^3}$, we'll differentiate $f$ three times, based on the reasoning that if $P(x) \le f^{(3)} \le Q(x)$ for polynomials $P$ and $Q$, then after integrating three times we will have an inequality involving polynomials with no terms of degree less than $3$. We calculate
$$f^{(3)}(x) = \cos x$$
For $x>0$, we have that
$$1-x \le \cos x \le 1$$
Let's integrate three times:
$$\int_0^x\int_0^y\int_0^z 1-w\, dw\,dz\,dy \le \int_0^x\int_0^y\int_0^z \cos w\, dw\,dz\,dy \le \int_0^x\int_0^y\int_0^z 1\, dw\,dz\,dy$$
Don't worry if you haven't seen triple integrals before: all we're doing is taking three integrals, one after the other.  This gives us
$$\frac{1}{6}x^3 - \frac{1}{24}x^4 \le x - \sin x \le \frac{1}{6}x^3$$

To finish, just have we divide by $x^3$ and take the limit as $x\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x = x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + o(x^5) \to \dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3} = \dfrac{1}{6} + o(x^2)$. From this the limit is $\dfrac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Note: the downvote is probably explained by this [meta question.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/18857/242)

Comment: How does one know whether to use big-O or little-o in these kinds of things?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can always use Taylor expansion near $x=0$ (as long as it is known to you), that is:
$$
\sin x = x - \frac1{3!}x^3 + o(x^5)
$$

Hence we will have:
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\sin x }{x^3}=\frac16
$$

Comment: Note: the downvote is probably explained by this [meta question.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/18857/242)