# How to solve this limit question without using L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Find the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x-x}{\tan^3 x}$$

I found the limit which is $-\frac{1}{6}$ by using L'Hopital Rule. Is there another way to solve it without using the rule? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use Taylor series?

Comment: Since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$, you have $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3}{\tan^3 x}=1$. 

So you want to compute:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x - x}{x^3}.$$ Not sure if that makes it easier. (Certainly makes the L'Hopital calculation easier.)

Comment: You can use Taylor expression of sine function .

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157903/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frac-tanx-xx3/158134#158134

Comment: Note

$$ \frac{\sin x - x}{x^3} = \frac{-\frac{1}{6}x^3 + O(x^5)}{x^3}$$

Comment: @Mathxx, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x-x}{\tan^3 x}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3} \underbrace{\left(\frac {x^3}{\tan^3 x}\right)}_{=1}$$

Now, let $$\mathrm L= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$$

Let $x=3y$, Since $x\to 0 \implies y \to 0$.

$$ \mathrm L= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin (3y)-3y}{(3y)^3}$$

\begin{align}
\mathrm L &= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac{3\sin y-4\sin^3 y-3y}{27y^3}\\
&= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{3}{27} \left(\frac{\sin y-y}{y^3}\right) -\frac{4}{27}  \lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin y}{y}\right)^3\\
&=\frac{3}{27} \cdot \mathrm L-\frac{4}{27}
\end{align}
$$\implies \mathrm L=-\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: But that only shows that $L=-\frac{1}{6}$ if $L$ exists. (I'm not the downvoter, though. Not sure why anybody would downvote.)

Comment: But if you want to use Taylor, this approach isn't needed. By *this* approach, the answerer hasn't shown $L$ exists - it could be infinite, for example, and $L=\frac{3}{27}L-\frac{4}{27}$ is still true. @YvesDaoust

Comment: Hmmm, not bad, but strictly speaking, you only proved that _if_ the limit you denoted by $L$ exists, it must be $-1/6$. You did not prove that it exists.

Comment: I didn't say $L=-4/27$, I said $-4$ should be $-\frac{4}{27}$. @YvesDaoust I was not correcting the answer, but an intermediate equation.

Comment: I won't downvote, but this is wrong. Unless you prove the limit exists this is like proving that $1+2+4+\dots+2^n+\dotsb=-1$, which can be done with a similar algebraic manipulation.