# limit of trigonometric functions without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x\to 0} [\csc^22x-\frac 1 {4x^2}]\ $

and

$\lim_{x\to y} \frac {\tan x- \tan y} {1-\frac{x}{y}(\tan x\tan y+1)}\ $

We have not learn L'Hôpital's rule in my class, we do the $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1\ $

I have not came up with anything yet

Comment: The second limit does not pose any problem as you can just plug $x=y$ and get $0$ as the answer. The first limit requires the use of advanced tools like Taylor series or L'Hospital's Rule and it won't be possible to get an answer just using algebra of limits. So if you have not studied these advanced techniques then this exercise is misplaced.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
Put $u=2x$ so we have
$$
\csc^2u-\frac 1 {u^2}=\frac{1}{\sin^2 u}-\frac 1 {u^2}=\frac{ (u+\sin u)(u−\sin u) }{u^2\sin^2u}=\left(1+\frac{\sin u}{u}\right)\frac{ u^2 }{\sin^2u}\frac{u-\sin u}{u^3}
$$

Since $\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\sin u}{u} = \lim_{u\to 0}  \frac{u}{\sin u}= 1$ we just need to find $\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{u-\sin u}{u^3}$.
This limit is $L=\frac 16$ (see below the link for a proof without derivatives or Taylor or l'Hopital).
So the original limit is
$$
\lim_{u\to 0}\csc^2u-\frac 1 {u^2}=\lim_{u\to 0}\left(1+\frac{\sin u}{u}\right)\frac{ u^2 }{\sin^2u}\frac{u-\sin u}{u^3}=2\cdot 1\cdot \frac 16=\frac 13
$$

See the answer for [$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{u-\sin u}{u^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157903/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frac-tanx-xx3/158134#158134)

For the second limit use the following hint:
$$
\frac {\tan x- \tan y} {1-\frac{x}{y}(\tan x\tan y+1)}=\frac{\tan(x-y)[\tan x\tan y+1]}{1-\frac{x}{y}(\tan x\tan y+1)}
$$

Comment: it should be minus not plus sorry

Comment: @DeepJ where minus?

Comment: the first problem, i have edited the thread you can see the correct one above

Comment: how do you get $ \ (\frac{2x}{\sin 2x}\)^2\frac{1}{4x^2}\ $

Comment: for the second plroblem can I just input x into y ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove some double-sided estimate for $1/\sin^2 x-1/x^2$ giving the first limit, using only $\lim_{h\to0}\sin h/h=1$ and $\lim_{h\to0}\cos h=1$:
$$\frac13\le\frac1{\sin^2 x}-\frac1{x^2}\le\frac1{3\cos^2 x/2}\tag1$$ for all $x\in(0,\pi)$.
**Proof:** We have $$\sin x=2\sin x/2\,\cos x/2,$$ implying
$$\frac1{\sin^2 x}=\frac14\left(\frac1{\sin^2 x/2}+\frac1{\cos^2 x/2}\right)$$
Replacing $x$ by $x/2^k$ and multiplying by $4^{-k}$ gives
$$\frac{4^{-k}}{\sin^2 x/2^k}-\frac{4^{-k-1}}{\sin^2 x/2^{k+1}}=\frac{4^{-k-1}}{\cos^2 x/2^{k+1}}$$ and thus (by monotony of $\cos x$)
$$4^{-k-1}\le\frac{4^{-k}}{\sin^2 x/2^k}-\frac{4^{-k-1}}{\sin^2 x/2^{k+1}}\le\frac{4^{-k-1}}{\cos^2 x/2}$$ 
Summing from $k=0$ to $k=n-1$ gives
$$\frac13(1-4^{-n})\le\frac1{\sin^2 x}-\frac{4^{-n}}{\sin^2 x/2^n}\le\frac{\frac13(1-4^{-n})}{\cos^2 x/2}$$
Now since $$\frac{4^{-n}}{\sin^2 x/2^n}=\frac1{x^2}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin x/2^n}{x/2^n}\right)^{-2},$$ letting $n\to\infty$ proves our claim (1). **qed**
It's clear that (1) together with the squeeze lemma means
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac1{\sin^2 x}-\frac1{x^2}\right)=\frac13,$$ and that won't change if we replace $x$ by $2x$.