# Is this way of evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$ rigorous?

Tags: trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Assume that you want to evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}.$$ Of course, you may apply $\textbf{de l'Hôpital's Rule}$, that's natural and simple. But what if you are required to avoid using the more advanced knowledge such as “de l'Hôpital”，“Taylor” and so on？Now,someone gives a solution for the problem as follows.

Since$$\begin{align*}\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}&=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{2x-\sin 2x}{(2x)^3}\\[4pt]&=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{2x-2\sin x\cos x}{(2x)^3}\\[4pt]&=\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x-\sin x+\sin x-\sin x\cos x}{x^3}\\[4pt] &=\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}+\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x(1-\cos x)}{x^3}\\[4pt] &=\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}+\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\\[4pt] &=\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1\cdot \frac{1}{2}\\[4pt] &=\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}+\frac{1}{8},\end{align*}$$ which sets up an equation on the limit, hence, by solving the equation, we obtain that$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}.$$
What about the solution? Is it rigorous? Hope to read your comments. Thank you!

Comment: If you know the limit exists, this shows it is $1/6$.

Comment: Yes,but he didn't prove the existence of that limit.

Comment: For methods which don't assume that the limit exists, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157903/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frac-tanx-xx3

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: To be more precise, this argument shows that, if you know that the limit exists *and is finite*, then that limit is $\frac16$. Both $L=\infty$ and $L=-\infty$ "satisfy" the equation $L=\frac14 L + \frac18$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo: when you wrote (after the third equality) $\sin\cos x$, you meant $\sin x\cos x$.

This proves correctly that *if the limit exists* then it must be equal to $\frac16$, but that's all.

Comment: Thanks! I have corrected that!

Comment: But it's  exactly the matter. He didn't show that the limit exists. And if he wants to show the existence, he need to know the limit value.

Comment: @mengdie1982 Yes, he didn't show that the limit exists. However, I disegree with the assertion that “if he wants to show the existence, he need to know the limit value”. Often, one can prove that a limit exists without computing it.

Comment: Sir,I understand your opinion. For example, we can show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$ exsits without evaluating the precise value. But for the problem I posted above, is there the similar method for proving the existence?

Comment: @mengdie1982 For instance, it can be proved that if a function $f$ is of class $C^3$, and if $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$, then the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}$ always exists. And then we can apply this to $f(x)=x-\sin(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! But it's more  more... advanced knowledge...

Comment: @mengdie1982 I don't understand what you're after. You've told by me and you've been told in the comments that what your friend did **doesn't prove that the limit exists**. What else do you want?