# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{(\sin^{-1}(x))^2} - \frac1{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

How to evaluate the following limit without L'Hôpital's rule
?$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{(\sin^{-1}(x))^2} - \frac1{x^2}\right)$$

**My attempt:**
$$\begin{align}L &= \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{(\sin^{-1}(x))^2} - \frac1{x^2}\right)\tag1\\& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x^2}{(\sin^{-1}(x))^2x^2} - \frac1{x^2}\right)\tag2\\& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x}{\sin^{-1}(x)}\right)^2\cdot \frac1{x^2} - \frac1{x^2}\tag3\\& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x}{\sin^{-1}(x)}\right)^2\cdot\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x^2} - \frac1{x^2}\tag4\\& =\left(1\right)^2\cdot\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x^2} - \frac1{x^2}\tag5\\& =\cdot\lim_{x\to 0} \frac1{x^2} - \frac1{x^2} \tag6\\& =0\tag7\end{align}$$

But later I realized, $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)\ g(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x) $ if and only if both  $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} g(x)$ are well defined and finite. Thus moving from $(3)$ to $(4)$ is absolutely wrong.

---

I don't have any more ideas about the problem.

Comment: use l´hopitals rule

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention it has to be solved without the rule.

Comment: I would start by taking $x=\sin t$ with $t \to 0$.

Comment: Are power series allowed?

Comment: @Gary I think evaluating $\lim_{t\to0 }\frac{1}{t^2} - \frac1{(\sin t)^2}$ is not an easy task either.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I don't know much about power series.

Comment: You will get $\sin^2 t$ and not $(\sin^{-1} t)^2 $. In fact you get, after some manipulations, $$
\lim _{t \to 0} \left( {\frac{{\sin t}}{t} + 1} \right)\left( {\frac{{\sin t}}{t}} \right)^{ - 2} \frac{{\sin t - t}}{{t^3 }} = 2\lim _{t \to 0} \frac{{\sin t - t}}{{t^3 }}.
$$

Comment: @Gary yup. Sorry a typo .-)

Comment: After @Gary 's hint, here is [another hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217081/determine-lim-x-to-0-fracx-sinxx3-frac16-without-lhospita).

Comment: Thank you everyone. It's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{1}{\arcsin(x)^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right)  = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{x^2 - \arcsin(x)^2}{\arcsin(x)^2 x^2} \right)$$
Taylor series of $ \arcsin(x) = x + x^3/6 + O(x^5) $ at $x \rightarrow 0$, in this way
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{x^2 - x^2 - x^4/3 - x^6/36}{(x + x^3/6)^2x^2} \right) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{- x^4/3 - x^6/36}{x^4 +  x^6/3 + x^8/36} \right) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{- x^4/3}{x^4} \right) = - \cfrac{1}{3}$$

Comment: I belive Taylor series are stronger than L'Hôpital's rule, and the OP is not even allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 2):

Using $$ \sin^{-1}(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{3 \, x^5}{40} + \mathcal{O}(x^7) $$ then $$\frac{1}{(\sin^{-1}(x))^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{3} - \frac{x^2}{15} - \frac{31 \, x^4}{945} + \mathcal{O}(x^6). $$ This gives $$ \frac{1}{(\sin^{-1}(x))^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} = - \frac{1}{3} - \frac{x^2}{15} - \frac{31 \, x^4}{945} + \mathcal{O}(x^6) $$ and the limit $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{1}{(\sin^{-1}(x))^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right) = - \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: I belive Taylor series are stronger than L'Hôpital's rule, and the OP is not even allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\arcsin x=t$ and then $x=\sin t$. So
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{1}{\arcsin(x)^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right) \\
& =& \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^2t - t^2}{t^2 \sin^2t}\\
& =& \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin t - t}{t^3}\cdot\frac{\sin t+t}{t}\cdot\frac{t^2}{ \sin^2t}\\
&=&-\frac16\cdot2=-\frac13.
\end{eqnarray}
Here
$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin t - t}{t^3}=-\frac16 $$
is used from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787506/is-this-way-of-evaluating-lim-x-to-0-fracx-sin-xx3-rigorous?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157903/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frac-tanx-xx3).