# Limit without Taylor expansion

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x - x}{x^3}$

I know it can be easily done by using Taylor expansion of sine function and L'Hopital. However, can we come up with a way to solve the limits using properties.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157903/evaluation-of-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frac-tanx-xx3/158134#158134

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = 3y$

$\sin(x) = \sin(3y) = 3\sin(y) - 4\sin^3(y)$

$$L = \lim_{y\to0}\frac{3\sin(y) - 4\sin^3(y) - 3y}{(3y)^3} = \lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin(y) 
+ y}{9y^3}+\lim_{y\to0}\frac{- 4\sin^3(y) }{27y^3}$$

$$L = \frac{L}{9}  - \frac{4}{27} $$

$$\frac{8L}{9} = - \frac{4}{27} $$

> $$L = \frac{-1}{6}$$

Comment: Well done, but it actually doesn't really prove the existence of the limit. But in the case where you proved that it exist, then it's well done :)