# Find the limit without use of L'Hôpital or Taylor series: $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find the limit without the use of L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor series

$$\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\right)$$

Comment: Why? What does sin mean without Taylor series? How is it defined?

Comment: By divination, the answer is $-1/3$.

Comment: my teacher give that limit for me and tell me there is a methode without use L'Hopital's rule or Taylor series . because of that i try to find any way without L'Hopital's rule or Taylor series

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285942/find-limit-without-using-lhopital-or-taylors-series?rq=1

Comment: And what does the teacher mean by sin x? Without using Taylor series.

Comment: You will need an inequality as in the first answer of the link, but the inequality comes from the terms of Taylor series of $\sin x$

Comment: also my teacher said there is a simple way to solve the problem . the school open after 2 day and if i have no answer he give me the answer after 2 day . notice that in secondary school in my country there is no L'Hopital or Taylor series just integral and derivative

Comment: That's a tough one and I have a certain inclination in what part of the world your school might be. But you say you can use derivatives except if the derivatives are in a numerator and denominator? That's odd. Now I would like to see a solution without any (anti) derivatives because I am clueless.

Comment: @imranfat and I will try . but if I try and know the solution .can I but the answer in my question or that is wrong ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let $I = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\right)$, we have:

$$\begin{align} 
I = & \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{(2x)^2} - \frac{1}{\sin^2(2x)}\right)\\
  = & \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{4 x^2} - \frac{1}{4 \sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\right)\\
\implies  4I = & \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\right)\\
\implies  3I = & \lim_{x\to 0}\left\{\left(\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\right)
                             -\left(\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\right)\right\}\\
=&-\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x} = -\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos^2 x} = -1\\
\implies I = & -\frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think this proof is flawed (excepting the case we know the limit exists).

Comment: @Chris'ssis: I agree. Proofs of this nature can be used to show that $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(2\pi\log_2(x))=0$ since $\sin(2\pi\log_2(2x))=\sin(2\pi\log_2(x))$.

Comment: @Chris'ssis: However, the question asks to find the limit, which presupposes that the limit exists.

Comment: @robjohn  Well, in my opinion, "Find the limit" may also lead you to the fact the limit doesn't exist. In my math books, there are situations where the limits don't exist, although the text is written like that "Find the limits".

Answer (score 9):

Well, you have 
$$\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sin x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{\sin x}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x\sin x}\right)\left(1+ \frac{x}{\sin x}\right)$$
Since the limit of $\left(1+ \frac{x}{\sin x}\right)$ is $2$, your answer will be
$$2\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x\sin x}\right)$$
$$=2\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)\left(\frac{\sin x - x}{x^3}\right)$$
$$=2\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x - x}{x^3}$$
An elementary calculus way of showing this limit is $-{1 \over 6}$ can be found [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?forumID=13&threadID=1993502&messageID=6865083).

So the overall answer is $-\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: What is sin x without using Taylor?

Comment: Defined geometrically through circles

Comment: And the limit? How is that defined geometrically?

Comment: $x$ is the angle, $\sin x$ is the sine of that angle. So you have to show the limit exists as the angle tends to zero, and find out what the limit equals.

Comment: can I ask you question ? is lim f(x)=lim f(x/a) when x>0 true ?

Comment: changing $x \to 3x$ does the trick

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x/a)$ for any $a \neq 0$, if the limit exists.

Comment: so now I have an idea to the solution of last limit you wrote it . can I put it or that is wrong in the term of this site ?

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh I don't know if there is a rule against that, but it's ok with me personally

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh : without Taylor sin x is meaningless in the context of taking limits without doing some pretty looking geometrical figures, the last limit is just as hard without using Taylor.

Comment: @Zarrax thanks alot

Answer (score 7):

sorry about to answer my Question but Zarrax's way and her comment lead me to the answer 
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x}{3}}{(\frac{x}{3})^3}$$

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{3\sin(\frac{x}{3})-4\sin^3(\frac{x}{3})-x}{x^3}$$

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{3\sin(\frac{x}{3})-4\sin^3(\frac{x}{3})-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{3(\sin(\frac{x}{3})-\frac{x}{3})-4\sin^3(\frac{x}{3})}{27(\frac{x}{3})^3}$$

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{3(\sin(\frac{x}{3})-\frac{x}{3})-4\sin^3(\frac{x}{3})}{27(\frac{x}{3})^3}=\frac{3L}{27}-\frac{4}{27}$$

$$L=\frac{3L}{27}-\frac{4}{27}$$

$$L=-\frac{1}{6}$$

$$2L=-\frac{1}{3}=\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\right)$$

thanks alot Zarrax
thanks for every one

Comment: Again, this requires a proof that the limit exists. The line $L = {3 \over 27}L - {4 \over 27}$ is also satisfied by $L = \infty$.

Answer (score 7):

We will use that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, which can be [shown geometrically](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151).

First note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\vphantom{()^2}x^2}-\frac1{\sin^2(x)}
&=\frac{\sin^2(x)-x^2}{x^2\sin^2(x)}\\
&=\frac{\sin^2(x)-x^2}{x^4}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{-2}\\
&=\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+1\right)\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{-2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Next, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x/2^{k-1})-2\sin(x/2^k)}{x^3}
&=\frac{2\sin(x/2^k)(\cos(x/2^k)-1)}{x^3}\\
&=\frac{\sin(x/2^k)}{x^3}\frac{2(\cos^2(x/2^k)-1)}{\cos(x/2^k)+1}\\
&=-2^{-3k}\left(\frac{\sin(x/2^k)}{x/2^k}\right)^3\frac2{\cos(x/2^k)+1}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^3}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{k-1}\frac{\sin(x/2^{k-1})-2\sin(x/2^k)}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty-2^{-2k-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x/2^k)}{x/2^k}\right)^3\frac2{\cos(x/2^k)+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty-2^{-2k-1}\\
&=-\frac16\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Plugging $(3)$ into $(1)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac1{\vphantom{()^2}x^2}-\frac1{\sin^2(x)}\right)
&=-\frac16\cdot2\cdot1^2\\
&=-\frac13\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$