# $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$ without de l'Hospital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know, how to calculate
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}
$$
without differential calculus. Calculating
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}
$$
using de l'Hospital's rule or Taylor expansion is also easy.

Is there a method to calculate the previous limit without de l'Hospital's rule or stronger tools?

Comment: The solution is provided by the second answer (user17762's one) given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134051/solving-lim-limits-x-to0-fracx-sinxx2-without-lhospitals-rule?rq=1

Comment: Thank you both! It is a trick I need.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I see you have created new tag called ([tag:elementary-proof]). It is recommended that a user who creates a new tag also creates [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/elementary-proof/info) - at least some basic info on the intended use of the new tag in the tag-excerpt. See, for example, [this answer on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17025). If some more details are needed, feel free to drop me a line [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19265805#19265805).