# $\lim_{x \to 0} {1-x\cot x\over x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

What's the value of this limit? I keep getting half, but the answer's 1/3. I think there might be a problem with writing ${x\cot x \over x^2 }$  as $ {\cos x \over x^2}$. Is there ?
I get (1-cosx)/x^2 on using this substitution, and if I use L'hôpital's Rule on this, I get the answer as sinx/2x = 1/2.

Edit: I can only use results like $\sin x=x$ and L'Hospital's rule. No series expansion.

Edit 2: Here's my attempt:

1/x^2 - cosx/(x*sinx) = 1/x^2 - (cosx/x^2)(x/sinx) = 1/x^2 - (cosx/x^2)(1) 
{Since sinx/x=1}
= (1-cosx)/x^2
Being a 0/0 case, L'hôpital's Rule:
sinx/2x = (1/2)(sinx/x) = 1/2, since sinx/x=1

Comment: $\sin x$ is not really equal to $x$, it is $x+o(x)$, so you can write $\sin x\sim_0x$, which will work well and relies only, in this case, on the high school limit: $\frac{\sin x}x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^2\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^3}\frac{x}{\sin x}
$$
The second fraction has limit $1$, so you just need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-\cos x+x\sin x}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sin x}{x}
$$

Your attempt is faulty, because
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}=\infty,\qquad
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cot x}{x}=\infty
$$
so you have a form $\infty-\infty$ and you ***can't*** use that $\sin x=x$ (which is false, by the way, avoid thinking like that).

Comment: But you've implicitly used sinx = x here, isn't that illegal because you have a third power term in the denominator? Won't you have to take a few more terms from the expansion?

Comment: @ArnavDas I use the theorem on product of limits. Since $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^3}=1/3$ (with l'Hôpital) and $\lim_{x\to0}x/\sin x=1$, the limit of the product is $1/3$.

Comment: Can the limit x tends to 0 be split across a + or - sign?

Comment: @ArnavDas It depends: the important thing is that each part has a finite limit (or both $+\infty$, both $-\infty$ or one finite and the other infinite). Surely you cannot split the given limit as $\lim_{x\to0}1/x^2-\lim_{x\to0}(\cot x)/x$. I added a comment on your attempt.

Comment: Can you explain why I can't split it? Didn't you give me a mutually exhaustive set of cases there, given one of them is infinite?Here, 1/x^2 is infinite, so doesn't that mean I can split it?

Comment: Can you elaborate once again on when it is forbidden to split it? When both or one of the terms diverges?

Comment: @ArnavDas There is no problem if both parts have a finite limit. But if you get a form such as $\infty-\infty$, you're not allowed to “simplify” like you did.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the series expansion
$$\cot(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^3}{45}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ what could also be obtained from
$$\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2 x^5}{15}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ followed by long division.

Comment: I need a solution without expansion, but only using standard results like sinx=x=tanx. Is there something wrong with taking xcotx/x^2 as cosx/x^2

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\frac13$, $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-x\cot x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2\tan x}=\frac{\frac13}{1}=\frac13.$$

Comment: Where does the second result come from? Is this standard?

Comment: @ArnavDad [One of several worth knowing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081306/lim-x-to0-frac-sin-x-xx3-without-de-lhospitals-rule).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{1-x\cot x}{x^2}=\dfrac{\tan x-x}{x^3}\cdot\dfrac x{\tan x}$$

Use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

Comment: Okay, so here if I take the term on the right (tanx/x) as 1 and then take tanx=x, won't I get zero? What's wrong with this? Am I doing something against the rules?

Comment: @ArnavDas, It will be $$\dfrac00$$ right?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this fraction first:
$$ {1-x\cot x\over x^2}=\frac{\tan x -x}{x^2\tan x}$$
and use  Taylor  expansion at order $3$ for the tangent:
$$\tan x=x+\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3),\quad\text{so }\quad \tan x- x =\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3)\sim_0 \frac{x^3}3.$$
Therefore, as $\tan x\sim_0 x$,
$$\frac{\tan x -x}{x^2\tan x}\sim_0 \frac{\frac{x^3}3}{x^3}=\frac13.$$

Comment: Can you check my edit?

Comment: @ArnavDas: It's fine. What was my typo (or were…)?

Comment: I meant my edit on the question.

Comment: Oh! I see. Well, you implicitly used that  near $0$, $\sin x\sim x$ (in the sense of asymptotic analysis) to simplify the numerator, but  you  should explain in a few words what you're doing, in my opinion.

Comment: How do I know which order do I have to stop at? You've taken terms till power 3, is that because the denominator was x^2?

Comment: I knew instantly the denominator was equivalent to $x^3$, so I stopped at order $3$.  It might have vanished at this order, in which case, I should have expanded a little further, but note the first computation would not have been lost – it would have required only to calculate the terms of degree $5$.

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hospital and using $\dfrac{\sin x}x\to1$,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin x}{3x^2}=\frac13.$$

Comment: In what does this differ from my answer?