# How to solve $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{x - \tan(x)}{x^2}$ Without L'Hospital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

How to solve $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{x - \tan(x)}{x^2}$ Without L'Hospital's Rule?
you can use trigonometric identities and inequalities, but you can't use series or more advanced stuff.

Comment: See  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhospital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: The set up is a little off, it would be easy to show it is $0$.

Comment: Did you mean $x^3$ in the denominator (which is much more interesting than $x^2$)? In that case, it's a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/157903/1242.

Comment: Also *very* similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/134051/1242

Answer (score 1):

Note that,

$\frac{\sin(x)-\tan(x)}{x^2} \leq \frac{x-\tan(x)}{x^2}\leq \frac{\tan(x)-\tan(x)}{x^2}=0$, for $\pi/2>x>0$ as $\sin(x) \leq x \leq \tan(x)$ for this interval.

For $x<0$ the inequalities are reversed because the functions tan and sin are even functions
$\frac{\sin(x)-\tan(x)}{x^2} \geq \frac{x-\tan(x)}{x^2}\geq \frac{\tan(x)-\tan(x)}{x^2}=0$, for $-\pi/2<x<0$ as  $\sin(x) \geq x \geq \tan(x)$ for this interval.

But,
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-\tan(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{\cos(x)-1}{x \cos(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-sin^2(x/2)}{(x/2)\cos(x)}=0$

So, $ 0 \leq \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\tan(x)}{x^2} \leq 0$

Therefore, $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\tan(x)}{x^2} = 0$

Comment: You can't apply $\sin x\sim x$ in the second equality.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for pointing out i am changing the answer