# How to solve this limit without L'Hospital's Rule?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am new to this site, so I don't know if this will appear correctly.

I need to solve this limit without L'Hospital's Rule:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}.$$

I know that the result is $\frac{1}{6}$ but I need a step-by-step solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the tip :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134051/solving-lim-limits-x-to0-fracx-sinxx2-without-lhospitals-rule?lq=1 ...correction. There is actually an answer for this here.

Comment: I found the link to the above question here: https://mathindex.wordpress.com/ You may want to bookmark this site if you are going to be looking for other limits.

Comment: Simplify the entire fraction by *x*, then use the fact that $\dfrac{\sin x}x\simeq\cos x$ around the origin $($plot the graphics of the two functions to visualize this$)$. We also have $1-\cos2t=2\sin^2t$, and $\lim\limits_{t\to0}\dfrac{\sin t}t=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Expand $\sin x$ into Taylor series around 0

Comment: Isn't that just l'Hôpital's rule in disguise? I'm not saying there's a better way, though.

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea what Taylor series is .. I am a medical student and I need to solve this as a part of a quiz for a friend and he is in high school, I asked him about taylor series, he doesn't know about that as well.. I am sorry but is there a differnet way? thank you so much

Comment: @MikeHaskel interesting thought... series works sometimes when Taylor's  theorem cannot be applied, it is more generic I think. But is very similar in style...

Comment: @MikeHaskel there is a different way using algebraic manipulation: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/217086/16192