# Limit without l'Hopital or Taylor series: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x\cos x- \sin x}{x^3}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

find the limit without l'Hôpital and Taylor rule :

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x\cos x- \sin x}{x^3}=?$$

My Try :

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x\cos x- \sin x}{x^3}\\=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x\cos x \sin x- \sin x\sin x}{x^3\sin x}\\=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x\sin 2x- \sin^2 x}{2x^3\sin x}\\~\\=?$$

what now ?

Comment: No l'Hôpital or series, but what _are_ you allowed to use? Certain standard/special limits?

Comment: Take out $\cos x$ and use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: These problems and the link referenced giving *special limits* are all built from using Taylor expansions, then we are asked to solve without it. Seems like ostriches who put their heads in the sand to not see the Taylor expansion...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are allowed to use the well-known limit
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$
then
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$$
follows easily and with a bit more effort (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)), you have:
$$\color{blue}{\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{3}\tag{1}}$$
Now for your limit and using $\color{blue}{(1)}$:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\cos x- \sin x}{x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\cos x\frac{x- \tan x}{x^3}\right)=-\lim_{x \to 0} \cos x \color{blue}{\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x - x}{x^3}} = -\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

Write

$$\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}+\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3} $$

The first fraction goes to $-\frac{1}{2}$ (it follows from $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$, no de l'Hopital or Taylor needed), while the second goes to $\frac{1}{6}$ (see [Solving $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{x - \sin(x)}{x^2}$ without L'Hospital's Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134051/solving-lim-limits-x-to0-fracx-sinxx2-without-lhospitals-rule) ). Overall

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^3} = -\frac{1}{3}. $$

Answer (score 3):

By a scaling of the variable, $$L:=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x\cos3x-\sin3x}{27x^3}.$$

Then by the triple angle formulas,

$$3x\cos3x-\sin3x=3x\cos x(1-4\sin^2x)-3\sin x+4\sin^3x\\
=(3-4\sin^2x)(x\cos x-\sin x)-8x\cos x\sin^2x,$$
so that

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}(3-4\sin^2x)\cdot\frac L{27}-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{8x\cos x}{27x}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}.$$

Using the $\text{sinc}$ limit, we can conclude

$$\frac89L=-\frac8{27}.$$