# Is it possible to evaluate this limit without series expansion and l'Hôpital's  rule?

Tags: limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limits without l'Hôpital](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157100/limits-without-lhopital)

I have a limit which is to be evaluated without using l'Hôpital's rule or series expansion.
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x} - \cos x}{2x \left ( \frac{e^{2x} - 1}{2x} - 1 \right ) }$$
Is it possible to evaluate it without l'Hôpital's rule or series expansion only using trigonometric and algebraic manipulation?

Comment: i think this is a duplicate .

Comment: can you send the link?? ... to the original ... i'll delete the question

Comment: Lol ... you are right ... i sounded like 'lopital' ... though they taught L hospital ... in school ... lol :D

Comment: how do i eliminate those e's??

Comment: Lol ... when did he ask??? he never told me

Comment: i would still like to know it ... without expanding ... if it's possible